# Date Format In Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, locale

I'm a total newbie with with Rails and Heroku.  I created an app with basic CRUD, which I  have deployed to Heroku.  A certain entity has a date property.  When I create or update with this value:

> 09/04/2011

It saves as:

> 04/09/2011

Running locally (with SQLite) I do not see this behavior.  I wondered if I needed to be more explicit about culture, so I modified config/locales/en.yml like so:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"  
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%m/%d/%Y"
```

This does not seem to have any affect.  Ideas?

UPDATE: Here is the controller action:

```
def create
    @entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to entries_path }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @entry, :status => :created, :location => @entry }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @entry.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the view:

```
<%= f.text_field :date, :value => (@entry.date.blank? ? '' : @entry.date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')), :class => 'date' %>
```

Here is the model:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which version of ruby you're using on Heroku this could be because of `Date.parse` assuming EU format (I think this started in 1.9:)

```
> Date.strptime("09/04/2011", "%m/%d/%y")
=> Fri, 04 Sep 2020
```

I would check that you're using the same version of ruby for your local development work, if this is the issue, you could override the setter on your attribute:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  def date=(v)
    if v.kind_of?(String)
      self.write_attribute(:date, Date.strptime(v.to_s, "%m/%d/%y"))
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Locally I am using ruby 1.8.7.  I can't quite figure out how to tell what version Heroku is running.  I'm happy to parse directly.  Where/how do I do that?  I have updated my post to show my existing code.  Thanks!

Comment: Regardless of the version, you could confirm this behavior by trying `Date.parse` from the `heroku console`.

Comment: Figured out console (such a noob).  Sure enough, it's parsing EU style.  What worked is to change stack from bamboo-mri-1.9.2 to bamboo-ree-1.8.7.  I have no idea other implications, but it solves this problem.  Coming from .NET I'm a little surprised not to find a simple way to set culture for the app.

Answer (score 2):

The locales file only determines how the date is rendered when it is output on the page not how the Db stores it. The Db knows how to store dates it is passed, are you using a date_select to allow the user to pick the date or are you using a text box?

Comment: I'm using a single textbox (so I can use a JS datepicker).  The form post contains "09/04/2011".

Comment: This answer is correct advice, but still is part question. It should be edited to be in form of an answer without questions.